# Load Rails app into existing HTML5 Page (using JQuery or iFrame)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, iframe

I have created a simple blogging application using Ruby on Rails.

I already have a existing HTML5 page that uses JQuery to dynamically load pages

I would like to load my Rails application into the existing HTML5 page using JQuery (or an iFrame if JQuery is not possible)

Thus my blogging application should form part of the existing HTML5 Website

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this, and I also cannot find any resource on the specific problem.

If anyone knows how this can be achieved (or some way to achieve a similar result)? This would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try using iframe since that seems straightforward solution given that your HTML5 website and blog application are on different domains. Also, remember to use same style-sheets in both websites so contents of iframe don't look odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the issue but here is what I'll do:

1. Put your existing HTML5 app in the `/public` directory of your rails app. All the files in `/public` are served statically and are served before rails routes. So your HTML5 app will work as before, put served by rails.
2. If there is no url collision, the other rails pages will work as if. But if you want to have a correct visual rendering, customize your [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

With this settings, you can serve the rails app and the HTML app over the same domain. Now you have to deal with your AJAX thing... You don't give enough detail. But basically, set your rails app to render only html parts and not entire html page. For that customize your layouts.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense than what I was trying to do

Comment: @user1296204 You're welcome. If the answer satisfies you, don't forget to accept it or vote up. Or complete your question so that I can improve my answer.